# Bulk rename files with numbering

Tags: bash, rename

How do I bulk rename multiple files named

*Image401.jpg, Image402.jpg,...*

to

*Image 001.jpg, Image002.jpg, ...* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to change '4' to '0'?

```
for f in Image4*.jpg
do
  # replace Image4 prefix with Image0
  newname="Image0${f#Image4}"
  mv "$f" "$newname"
done
```

Or you want to subtract 400 from the numeric part? Or something else?

Comment: `mv "$f" Image0"${f#Image4}"` is a much faster and safer way to do this.  The `$( echo | sed )` approach, even if it works on filenames like `Image401.jpg`, is not very robust as it will mangle filenames containing odd characters or spaces, and is much slower because of the extra temporary subshell and processes created for every single file.

Comment: All true - and it wasn't even the best sed command to use.

Answer (score 2):

Under Linux, to change the first `4` in the file names to `0`:

```
rename 4 0 Image4*.jpg
```

Under Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives, `rename` is a different file renaming program, which is based on a Perl expression. Either call `rename.ul` instead, or call the Perl renaming script:

```
rename 's/4/0/' Image4*.jpg
```